# Title in article class not centered

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles, article

I'm going for a centered title and subtitle in the article document class. No matter what I do, I can only seem to get the subtitle to horizontally center, but never the document title.

Can anyone help me horizontally center the "Flux Capacitors" title? I've tried a bunch of combinations of `\begin{center}\end{center}` and `\centering` all over the place.

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Here's what I've got:

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% get rid of section numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\title{
  \begin{center}
    \textbf{Flux Capacitors}
    \newline\large\textit{PHY410/PHY610 Introduction to Back to the Future Physics}
  \end{center}
}

\date{}


\begin{document}

\author{John Smith}

\maketitle


\section{Secction One}

Some text here.

\section{Section Two}

Some text here too.

\subsection{Subsection One}

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

When compiled, it looks like this:
[image]

**EDIT after question has been answered:**

The suggested solutions all involved removing the `center` environment from the title and breaking the subtitle out of the title.

Another thing that all of the answers do is use `\\` for the newline rather than `\newline`.

What's wild is that the messed up centering always seemed to happen actually as a consequence of me using `\newline` rather than `\\`. Thanks to @Denis & @Mico for suggesting to break this into something of the shape:

```tex
\title{\textbf{my title}}}\\
\large\textit{my subtitle}
```

What's crazy is that if I do this instead:

```tex
\title{\textbf{my title}}}
\newline\large\textit{my subtitle}
```

The broken centering comes back.

In fact, my original code (albeit wonky) worked perfectly as soon as I replaced `\newline` with `\\`. I have no idea why this is, but this solved my problem. Thanks all!

Comment: Center, \centering and tabular redefine \\ but not \newline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\title{\textbf{Flux Capacitors}\\
\large\textit{PHY410/PHY610 Introduction to Back to the Future Physics}}
\date{\today}
\author{John Smith}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Secction One}
Some text here.
\end{document}
```

Here everything is well centered.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Indeed this is more straightforward than what I was doing. I also discovered, thanks to your answer, that what seemed to break the built-in title centering in the article class was my use of `\newline` rather than \\. More detail added as an edit to my original question above. Thanks again!

Comment: @HeatherMiller You're welcome. Mico's answer gives more clueq on what was going wrong in your original code.

Answer (score 5):

In the `article` document class, the argument of the `\title`, `\author`, and `\date` directives are typeset inside a `center` environment. Specifically, the low-level command `\@maketitle` is defined as follows:

```
\def\@maketitle{%
  \newpage
  \null
  \vskip 2em%
  \begin{center}%
  \let \footnote \thanks
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large
      \lineskip .5em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\large \@date}%
  \end{center}%
  \par
  \vskip 1.5em}
```

Note, in particular, the `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` directives.

I don't think it's good practice to embed a `center` environment in another `center` environment. I'd therefore go with

```
\title{\textbf{Flux Capacitors}\\ 
  \large\itshape PHY410/PHY610 Introduction to Back to the Future Physics}
```

Comment: Sure, but what is the difference with what is suggested in my answer?

Comment: @Denis - My answer articulates a factual reason for not using a `center` environment in the argument of `\title`. Some people may appreciate this piece of information.

Comment: I see now. that more been added.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it made no sense for me to attempt to re-center the title. I also discovered, thanks to your answer, that what seemed to break the built-in centering was my use of `\newline` rather than \\. More detail added as an edit to my original question above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `titling` package in order to create you own `\subtitle` command that is then taken into account by the `\maketitle` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

% get rid of section numbers
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
\gdef\SubTitle{#1}}
\newcommand{\SubTitle}{}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{%
\centering \large \textit{\SubTitle}}
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\bfseries}

\title{Flux Capacitors}
\subtitle{PHY410/PHY610 Introduction to Back to the Future Physics}
\date{}
\author{John Smith}

\begin{document}



\maketitle


\section{Secction One}

Some text here.

\section{Section Two}

Some text here too.

\subsection{Subsection One}

Some more text.

\end{document}
```